# react-native-modal-datetime-picker issue with daylight saving time zone

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, moment-timezone

I have been using **react-native-modal-datetime-picker** package for my *react native mobile application* and came across an issue.

In the date picker I need to have a default selected date as `'1985-08-17'` and when the time zone is `America/Mexico_City (-05:00)` the default selected date becomes the *previous day* which is `'1985-08-16'`.

Is there any thing that I have done wrong in the below code sample?

```
<DateTimePicker
    isVisible={true}
    date={new Date('1985-01-17')}
    onConfirm={()=>()}
    onCancel={()=>()}
    mode={'date'}
/>
```

In the same CDT time zone when I change the device timezone to `America/Chicago` this issue is not reproducible.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ?

Comment: not yet @morgane1806

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this as well. The reason for it is because react-native-modal-datetime-picker is using your **local** timezone, whereas `new Date(...)` uses **UTC**.

You can fix it by telling react-native-modal-datetime-picker to use UTC as well like this

```
<DateTimePicker
    isVisible={true}
    date={new Date('1985-01-17')}
    onConfirm={()=>()}
    onCancel={()=>()}
    mode={'date'}
    timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0} - its worked for me.

Comment: Note this is not recommended to be used due to some android issues with it https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/528